# How to add an additional fake null column to select result in Informix?

Tags: informix

I need to select an additional column which does not exist in the current table in order to unload the data in the correct format.

Suppose I have two different tables as follows.

**

```
tab1 
----
col1 col2 col3

tab2
---
col1 col2
```

**

Suppose I need to unload 1000 records from tab2 and need to load them into tab1. But there is a mismatch when considering the number of columns. But I'm ok to enter null values for col3 when loading the data into tab1

So my unload command is as follows

```
unload to data.unl select col1, col2, null as col3 from tab2;
```

Then I can load the contents of `data.unl` into tab1. But my problem is that I get a syntax error when I'm trying to unload the data in that way. Please correct me. Someone can argue that I can use a simple insert command with selecting the data from the tab2. But in my actual use-case it is not possible because data volume is so high and I hope to use the `ipload`.

Here is my sample error:

```
nwn@nwnhost$ echo "select CURRENT as col1,null as col2 from sysdual" | dbaccess sysmaster

Database selected.


  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 1
Near character position 29


Database closed.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could arrange for `ipload` to only load the columns you have and default the others (`col3`) to null, but you can also generate the null column as in my answer.  You could also simply append a pipe symbol to each line in the output file (with `sed` or any other tool of your choosing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the `NULL` to the desired type:

```
SELECT CURRENT AS col1, NULL::INTEGER AS col2
  FROM sysmaster:"informix".sysdual;
```